# Redirection error with CAS Oauth authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, cas, jasig

I have a REST service that is running on https://localhost:9090. 
In order to provide token based authentication with Oauth2.0 for consumers of my REST service, I have cloned the 4.2 version of CAS from repository https://github.com/leleuj/cas-pac4j-oauth-demo and deployed only cas2.war (cas server) on tomcat 7. From the browser, I hit this URL :

https://localhost:8443/cas2/login?response_type=code&client_id=this_is_the_key&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9090%2Fv1%2Ffiles%2Fafb2265b-39e9-4172-bccc-e3f43700874e

I got the cas login page and after the successful login with valid credentials (leleuj::leleuj), I was not redirected to my service api as mentioned in the URL. Instead, the browser still shows the success cas login page. Is there something wrong in what I am doing? Sorry if this is a basic question, I am somewhat new to CAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm leleuj on github, it feels a question for me ;-) Indeed, this doesn't work running `mvn jetty:run`, but if you run the webapps in Tomcat, it works, I haven't investigated more as CAS 5 is out now!

Comment: Thanks Jerome! As you said, it works fine with tomcat. I have to secure my REST APIs with CAS oauth. The consumers of my API can be desktop/mobile/webapp. Since oauth2.0/authorize always redirects to cas login page, I wanted to avoid that and enabled REST protocol. Things work fine with rest but the difficulty is I have to make two calls every time to get access token 1) to create service ticket and 2) to get access token with the ST. Is there any way to optimize this?